# Handle less closing the stdout pipe

Tags: python, bash

Say I have this code:

```py
for i in range(200):
    print("\n" * 200)
```

and I run it like this:

```sh
$ python oops.py | less
```

then quit less before scrolling down, Python throws an exception:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

How do I handle this cleanly? Ideally I want to behave like `cat` does and silently stop, however the exception doesn't appear to have any information in it other than "invalid argument".

Comment: Side note: I don't know why the exception is being ignored in my example, but in my main program it has a full stack trace

Comment: Look at the second highest voted answer in the link @0stone0 shared.